# I am using gh-pages to deploy a github page but I'm getting an error now when it was working fine before

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

in my package.json, I have the proper homepage. I installed gh-pages and added these two scripts

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

This is everything that shows up in the terminal

```
git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-31T04_47_04_970Z-debug.log
```

What could be the issue and how do I fix it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need to configure the [`gh-pages` npm task](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages) with its [`repo` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#optionsrepo)

> ### `options.repo`
>
> ```
> type: string
> default: url for the origin remote of the current dir (assumes a git repository)
> ```
>
> By default, `gh-pages` assumes that the current working directory is a git repository, and that you want to push changes to the origin remote.
>
> **If instead your script is not in a git repository, or if you want to push to another repository, you can provide the repository URL in the repo option**.
>
> Example use of the repo option:

```
/**
 * If the current directory is not a clone of the repository you want to work
 * with, set the URL for the repository in the `repo` option.  This usage will
 * push all files in the `src` config to the `gh-pages` branch of the `repo`.
 */
ghpages.publish('dist', {
  repo: 'https://example.com/other/repo.git'
}, callback);
```

Comment: Where would I put this option in the gh-pages.js?

Comment: @austinlkillian You can pass it as parameter in your package.json (https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/290#issuecomment-514514946)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve the problem by installing the latest version of Node.js. That fixed everything right up, thanks!